# How do you delete an existing site column from a Document Library?

Tags: document-library, site-column

I can add existing site columns to a document library, but I can't delete them. For example I added a Description site column, but I can't remove it.

Answer (score 2):

When you add a page content field it will created as sealed column and by default sharepoint doesn't allow to delete sealed columns. So to delete it via pwoershell.

```
$web = Get-SPWeb “https://sharepoint.comm/”   //this will get site collection reference
$list = $web.Lists["List Name "]   //get the list / library where Column is added
$field = $list.Fields["Columns name "]  // get the field /column which you want delete
$field.Allowdeletion = $true  //no allow for deletion
$field.Sealed = $false  //Now break the seal
$field.Delete()     //deleted
$list.Update()   //Update the list.
```